# Changing date value in Pandas to another

Tags: python, pandas

Have a dateframe like that:

[image]

Trying to change '2001-01-01' value in column to date (function of today's date). But this one approach does not work:

```
date = dt.date.today()
df.loc[df['dat_csz_opzione_tech'] == '2001-01-01', 'dat_csz_opzione_tech'] = date
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What doesn't work? This _should_ work. Unless your DataFrame has `'dat_csz_opzione_tech'` actually capitalized and you're getting a key error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
import time
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'dat_csz_opzione_tech' :['2001-02-01','2001-01-01','2001-03-01','2001-04-01']})
todaysdate = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
df.loc[df['dat_csz_opzione_tech'] == '2001-01-01', 'dat_csz_opzione_tech'] = todaysdate
print df
```

Output

```
      dat_csz_opzione_tech
0           2001-02-01
1           2017-02-14
2           2001-03-01
3           2001-04-01
```

Comment: You're assuming that OP actually has strings... why?